# How do I make the content CSS property syntax work in IE & Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am pretty new to all this so I may have missed a few important steps of the learning process. I have this code of mine, used for a top nav bar. Everything seems to be working fine in chrome, however when I open the `.html` document in IE or firefox it does not display the images (keep in mind that I can't just do the `<img>` tag because I want the image to change when hovered over). I have been trying to solve this for a few hourers, but still can't seem to fix it. All I know is that the `content` syntax in the css doesn't work in IE unless `!DOCTYPE` is specified. I have specified the document with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which should be correct. Any idea on how to make this work properly in IE and Firefox?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      
<title>Biologi</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/gif" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
    p.light {font-weight:lighter;}
    a{text-decoration: none}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul width="100%">
            <a href="index.html"><li class="logoli"><div class="logo"></div></li></a>
            <a href="index.html"><li><div class="archive"></div><div><p class="light">ARKIV</p></div></li></a>
            <a href="index.html"><li><div class="contact"></div><div><p class="light">KONTAKT</p></div></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #93b873;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2d2d2d;
}
#menu ul{
    height: 82px;
}
#menu li{ 
    text-align: center;
    height: 76px;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #2d2d2d;
    float: left;
}
#menu ul .logoli{
    width: 350px;
}
#menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #282828;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
#menu li:hover {
    background-color: #88ad6a;
}
#menu a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu a:hover .archive{
    content: url('archive2.png') no-repeat;
}
.archive{
    content:url('archive1.png') no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    margin:auto;
}
.contact{
    content:url('contact1.png') no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    margin:auto;
}
.logo{
    content:url(logo1.png) no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 70px;
    margin:auto;
}
#menu a:hover .contact{
    content: url('contact2.png') no-repeat;
}

#menu a:hover .logo{
    content: url('logo2.png')no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Not totally related but you can't have an anchor tag as a child of a UL. A UL can only have LI elements as children. You should move your anchor tags inside the LI tags.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with inserting an image using the CSS property [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) with a URL value. The syntax used is correct as such, but it is not part of the CSS 2.1 specification, only described in CSS3 drafts and only partly implemented in browsers. The issue can be reduced to a simple case like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>content issue</title>
<style>
#foo { content: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100') }
</style>
<div id=foo></div>
```

This works on some browsers, but not all, not even on all modern browsers. By CSS 2.1, the `content` property is allowed for `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements only. If your actual code really has an empty `div` element, you can use a pseudo-element, since you do not want to *replace* some content by an image with CSS, only *insert* an image:

```
#foo:after { content: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100') }
```

Comment: To be clear, the issue lies in specifying `content` on an element versus a `:before`/`:after` pseudo-element, not in the use of a URL value as it might seem.